# ad-hoc (IBSS) network cross platform leaves macOS unreachable

Tags: network, wifi, ad-hoc

So I wanted to use an ad-hoc network that uses both Linux and macOS. However, the macOS device says to be connected, but is not reachable.

Network is created via the wireless hotbar on macOS or via iwconfig on linux. If the network is created on Linux with a WEP password, it is visible on macOS and when joining it on macOS a functional password field pops up. After filling it the right password, macOS says to be connected to the ad-hoc network.

However, when connected, the macOS device is not reachable; it can't ping anybody else and nobody can ping it.

So far, I tried

- Manually setting my IP
- Manually adding routes for the other IP's (sudo route add -host 192.168.0.2 -interface en1)
- Manually enabling / disabling arp (ifconfig en1 arp)